# Bash/PHP extract URL from HTML via regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash

Is there any easy way to extract this URL in bash/or PHP?

```
http://shop.image-site.com/images/2/format2013/fullies/kju_product.png
```

From this HTML code?

```
<a href="javascript: open_window_zoom('http://shop.image-site.com/image.php?image=http://shop.image-site.com/images/2/format2013/fullies/kju_product.png&pID=31777&download=kju.png&name=13011 KELLYS Kju: 490mm (19.5&quot;)',550,366);">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With perl you could do a match and a capture

```
perl -n -e 'print "$1\n" if (m/image=(.*?)\&/);'
```

This captures everything between `image=` and the next `&` and prints it `$1`.

For more on regular expressions, see [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) or http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: You guys rock! Works like a charm. This is regex? It is seems easier.

Sometimes I need regex, but it is really hard to learn. :)

Comment: @Adrian It's a skill well worth learning. Start with simple regular expressions and expand on that.

Comment: To second what Olaf said, it's one of the most powerful tools a programmer has.

Answer (score 2):

In `bash`, you can try the following:

```
sed 's/.*image=\(http:\/\/[^&]*\).*/\1/g'
```

**Update**:
The solution above performs substitution rather than extraction. The line containing the pattern (required url) is replaced by the pattern itself. However, the substitution isn't in-place.

Comment: Do you really need to match the beginning of the line and the end of the line?

Comment: @L0j1k I didn't understand what do you mean by matching beginning of line and end of line. I didn't used `^` or `$` in my solution.

Comment: Aloha. That's exactly right. And if you're going to use a substitution match (which will destroy the original data, something the asker may not know about), you *should* be using `^` and `$`. It all comes down to greedy matching, like sputnick said.

Comment: @L0j1k Ok. Now, I understand what you meant.

Comment: Since you know what's up now, I want to undownvote this, but I can't unless you edit your answer. If you edit your answer to include a disclaimer that your answer will perform a substitution (and therefore destroy the original data), then I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever way you decide to dress it up, you could simply split with the delimiter equal to `?image=` and then split the second token you receive (i.e. `result[1]`) with a simple `&` delimiter. The first result from that split is your answer.

However, a pure regex match would look something like: `m#image=(a-z0-9\:/\.\-)&#i`. You can take that regex and put it wherever you want to get your result stored in `$1`. Despite what a lot of people think, you do not have to match the beginning of a line and the end of a line to match a result.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//a/@href' file://file.html |
    grep -oP 'image=\Khttp://.*?\.png'
```

You can use an URL instead of a local file :

```
http://domain.tld/path
```

Or if you had already extracted the line to parse in the `$string` variable :

```
grep -oP 'image=\Khttp://.*?\.png' <<< "$string"
```